# Apache: End of script output before headers

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I have seen many other answers and tried but they arent helping.

My Python code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
print ("""
    <TITLE>CGI script ! Python</TITLE>
    <H1>This is my first CGI script</H1>
 """)
```

Its location and permission

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root   root   161 May 24 02:42 mypython.py
[root@server cgi-bin]# pwd
/var/www/mysite.com/cgi-bin
```

Virtual-Host conf

```
[root@server cgi-bin]# cat /etc/httpd/sites-available/mysite.com.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html
    ServerAlias mysite.com
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/mysite.com/cgi-bin/"
    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mysite.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mysite.com/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
[root@server cgi-bin]#
```

While trying to access , I am getting below error

```
[Wed May 24 02:42:53.958318 2017] [cgid:error] [pid 7943] [client 192.168.56.1:52390] End of script output before headers: mypython.py
[Wed May 24 02:42:54.661338 2017] [cgid:error] [pid 7939] [client 192.168.56.1:52391] End of script output before headers: mypython.py
[Wed May 24 02:42:59.383215 2017] [cgid:error] [pid 7940] [client 192.168.56.1:52392] End of script output before headers: mypython.py
```

Please let me know if more information required.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem might be the

```
print()
```

In Python 2.7.12 at least this prints **()** and not a blank line as you might expect

Please post the exact output of the script as it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I take it you web-server is running as root otherwise your execute file permission is wrong.

Secondly if you run the file from the command line it outputs:

```
Content-Type: text/html


    <TITLE>CGI script ! Python</TITLE>
    <H1>This is my first CGI script</H1>
```

Note there are two empty lines not one, this is bad as there should be only one see https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html

But if you change your code slightly to remove the other empty line it works.

```
print ("""<TITLE>CGI script ! Python</TITLE>
    <H1>This is my first CGI script</H1>
 """)
```

Comment: I have removed the empty line but its not working still. Please help.